CI: how to speed up step installing perl modules
In my pipeline I  have the following steps:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

...

    - name: install additional packages
      # graphics: transfig gnuplot inkscape 
      # pdf utilities: poppler-utils (pdfinfo, pdftotext)
      # Perl modules Capture::Tiny in libcapture-tiny-perl
      run: sudo apt-get install -y transfig gnuplot inkscape poppler-utils libcapture-tiny-perl
    - name: install perl modules
      run: |
        sudo cpan App::cpanminus
        sudo cpanm Cwd File::Spec::Functions Capture::Tiny DateTime DateTime::Format::ISO8601

Whereas the first step runs 30 secs the second one sometimes requires 3-4 minutes.
I wonder whether on ubuntu the modules are available via apt-get or there is another way to speed up...Caching?

Start by avoiding the needless installation of cpanm and core modules Cwd and File::Spec::Functions. Skipping the tests (cpan -T) would greatly speed things up. You could also preinstall them so that all you need it to copy the "installed" files. ("Caching", as you called it.)

@ikegami You mean, I dont need cpanm at all and can install all with cpan?
I will try today. Also the -T option I will try.
About superfluous modules: Both Cwd and File::Spec::Functions were not present. I really had to install.
Maybe you refer to another version of perl???or of ubuntu??

@ikegami I dont know how to do preinstall/caching... could you point me to a resource with more information?

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/choosing-what-your-workflow-does/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows

Why do you install Capture::Tiny twice?

Make sure you have the perl package installed. perl-base has lots of the core modules removed.

Then install libdatetime-format-iso8601-perl if you want to use your package manager

Re "About superfluous modules: Both Cwd and File::Spec::Functions were not present.", ah, a lobotomized installation of Perl. Your distro split Perl into two package, and you only have one installed. Installing the rest of Perl using apt will do the trick.

Re "I dont need cpanm at all and can install all with cpan", Yes. Or as clamp pointed, you can install the missing module using apt. That would be best and fastest. Since you can install everything using apt, you should, and it will solve your problem.

Re "I dont know how to do preinstall/caching", You install them into a specific directory. We use cpanm --self-contained --local-lib=...

First I tried to replace cpanm by cpan, this works.
The time elapsed is sometimes about 7m26.
To compare, the general installation of texlive is something around 30s and installation of some aditional packages beyond texlive with apt-get is about 17-25s.
With option -T it was around 1m40s. Ok really faster.
Is it less safe?

Install all of the modules using apt or apt-get.

File::Spec::Functions is provided by system package perl or perl-base.
Cwd is provided by system package perl or perl-base.
Capture::Tiny is provided by system package libcapture-tiny-perl.
DateTime::Format::ISO8601 by system package libdatetime-format-iso8601-perl.


If I do this, the installation by apt-get does not become significantly longer.
But I spare the separate installation with cpan.
This seems the best solution.

Should be way faster, even. No running tests. It's just "unzipping".

You can tell both cpan and cpanm to install without tests which will be much faster:
sudo cpan -T App::cpanminus
sudo cpanm -n Cwd File::Spec::Functions Capture::Tiny DateTime DateTime::Format::ISO8601


I tried: really 7m shrinks to 1:40.
